# can you reroute a view path just like controllers in codeigniter 3.1.11?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a question. Is it possible to reroute a path (views path to be specific) just like in controllers in CI 3.1.11? I am migrating the site from 1.7.2 to 3.1.11.

for example: $this->load->view('header');

the view is now in views/partials/header.php. Maybe there's a way to make its path rerouted to the same load view without changing its directory.

Answer (score 0):

yes you can put your files in folder

```
view 
    +partials
      +header.php
```

---

```
 $this->load->view('partials/header');
```